# AngularJS testing with Protractor- Cannot read property 'click()' of undefined, even though 'undefined' element has already been used

Tags: angularjs, protractor, automated-tests, undefined

I am developing a test suite for an AngularJS app, and have hit a strange problem while writing one of the test scripts which I can't seem to work out.

The test is:

```
it('should navigate to the Charts page', function() {
    console.log("Start Charts page test");
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(chartsMenuBtn), 5000).then(
        browser.actions().
        mouseMove(chartsMenuBtn).
        chartsMenuBtn.click().
        browser.wait(EC.urlIs(site + '/#/charts'), 5000).
        perform()
    );
})
```

When I run the test, it fails, giving the reason:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

The element that `click()` is being called on is `chartsMenuBtn`, which I have defined globally with:

```
var chartsMenuBtn = element(by.linkText("Charts"));
```

So the element clearly is defined. On top of that, Protractor only seems to think that it's undefined at the point at which a call to `click()` is called on it- but it was actually used twice directly preceding that, so if it was undefined at the point that Protractor is claiming it is, it would surely have been undefined in the two prior uses too...?

I actually put a `browser.call(console.log("chartsMenuBtn: ", chartsMenuBtn));` line in just before the `browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(chartsMenuBtn), 5000).then(` line, just to make sure that it was not undefined, and this prints the following in my console:

> ```
> chartsMenuBtn:  ElementFinder {
> browser_:
>  ProtractorBrowser {
>    controlFlow: [Function],
>    schedule: [Function],
>    setFileDetector: [Function],
>    getExecutor: [Function],
>    getSession: [Function],
>    getCapabilities: [Function],
>    quit: [Function],
>    actions: [Function],
>    touchActions: [Function],
>    executeScript: [Function], ...
> ```

showing that the element clearly is defined at the point at which it is used.

Anyone have any ideas what the actual reason why this test is failing is? How can I get it to run correctly?

Comment: I don't know protractor, but in your code, the "chartsMenuBtn" where do you call "click()" is no the variable "chartsMenuBtn", but a property of the return value of mouseMove(chartsMenuBtn), because you end the previouis sentence with a point, not a semicolon.

Comment: Ah, ok, it seems I am chaining the promises incorrectly then. I gave what you suggested a go, but now get an error message saying: `Failed: unknown error: Element.... is not clickable at point (40, 229). Other element would receive the click.: `. It seems to indicate that the click would be received by the dialog (the dialog on which the button I'm trying to click is displayed), rather than by the button...

Comment: As a said, I don't know protractor, but if those are promises, then most likely you need to do something like this: `mouseMove(chartsMenuBtn).then(function () { return chartsMenuBtn.click(); }).then(function () { return browser.wait(EC.urlIs(site + '/#/charts'), 5000); }).perform();`

Comment: They are promises- but I am expecting the line `browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(chartsMenuBtn), 5000).then(` to cause the test to wait for the `chartsMenuBtn` element to be clickable before it runs the code inside `i.e. the call to `chartsMenuBtn.click();`... which it doesn't seem to be doing because it says another element would receive the click...

Comment: I gave what you wrote in your comment a go, but now get an error that says: `Failed: browser.wait(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).perform is not a function`... I'm not sure why that is...?

Comment: Probably you need to call perform() inside a .then(function() {}) too, however I don't know how to get a reference to that function if you don't get it as a return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed in the comments your `then()` looks a bit strange. Also you actually don't need it in your case.

Here my suggestion:

```
it('should navigate to the Charts page', function() {
    console.log("Start Charts page test");
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(chartsMenuBtn), 5000);
    //browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(blockingElement), 5000);
    chartsMenuBtn.click(); //works, if the element is defined as you said
    browser.wait(EC.urlIs(site + '/#/charts'), 5000);
})
```

If (as you say) your button is not clickable, when you `click()` it, try to do `browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(blockingElement), 5000)`.

That "isNotClickable" Message is bytheway less wrong than "cannot read property of undefined". "isNotClickable" says it's valid code, but the webpage currently does not let you execute this action. "cannot read property" tells you, your code is wrong.

In general you find your solutions usually, if you just check [the Protractor API here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api). All useful commands are listed there.