# Testing AngularJS with Protractor- test fails because element is not clickable despite waiting for elementToBeClickable...?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, automated-tests, wait

I have encountered a strange problem while writing up one of the tests in a test suite I am developing for an AngularJS application using Protractor.

While initially developing the tests, I was using a call to `browser.pause()` to ensure that I manually had to tell the tests to execute each line while running through the test scripts. I am now happy that the tests that I have written so far are executing correctly & all pass/ fail correctly depending on their criteria.

I now want to remove the call to `browser.pause()` so that the script can run through each of the tests automatically, without the need for any user interaction. However, because the application is Angular, doing this has caused some issues with timing/ waiting for elements to load before the test steps that reference them are executed- so I am currently going through each of the tests, and trying to ensure that they are allowing the required times for elements to load/ waiting for an element before interacting with it, etc.

When I run my test script at the moment, it is failing on the second test (navigate to the Export page), which I have written as follows:

```
it('should navigate to the Export page', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(exportMenuBtn), 25000).then(
        browser.actions().mouseMove(exportMenuBtn).perform().then(
            exportMenuBtn.click().then(
                function() {
                    console.log("Export page test completed ");
                    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(VM + '/#/export');
                }
            )
        )
    );
});
```

The error message I get in the command line where I'm running my script says:

> Failed: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (40, 301). Other element would receive the click:

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope ult-loading modal-message ng-animate in-remove in-remove-active" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" window-class="ult-loading modal-message" size="sm" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;; transition-property: opacity;transition-duration: 0.15s;">...</div>
```

> (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.89)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

which indicates to me that the `exportMenuBtn` element is not 'clickable' at the point at which my test script is trying to call `.click()` on it. But this doesn't make sense, since I have used the line `browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(exportMenuBtn), 25000)` to wait for the `exportMenuBtn` element to be clickable before I try to click it...

I have tried increasing the time that I wait for the element to be clickable, but this doesn't seem to have made a difference...

Can anyone explain why this test is failing? How can I ensure that the test waits for the `exportMenuBtn` element to be clickable before it tries to click it?

**Edit**

So I tried doing what @Ernst Zwingli suggested in their answer- added a function to close the dialog to my `spec.js` file with:

```
var pageLoaded = function() {
    var blockingElement = $('div[window-class="ult-loading modal-message"');
    return EC.invisibilityOf(blockingElement);
}
module.exports = new pageLoaded();
```

and then updated the test script to:

```
it('should navigate to the Export page', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.wait(pageLoaded, 5000);
    exportMenuBtn.click();
    browser.wait(pageLoaded, 5000);
    browser.wait(EC.urlIs(VM + '/#/export'), 5000);
});
```

But my test script still fails, giving the same error message:

> Failed: unknown error: Element

```
<a href="#/export" target="_self">...</a>
```

> is not clickable at point (40, 301).
>
> Other element would receive the click:

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope ult-loading modal-message ng-animate in-remove in-remove-active" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" window-class="ult-loading modal-message" size="sm" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;; transition-property: opacity;transition-duration: 0.15s;">...</div>
```

> ```
>  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.89)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
> ```

The dialog that seems to be causing the issue is defined in Dialog/service.js with:

```
function wait(msg, progress, title) {
    // Create a wait dialog
    var dlg = dialogs.wait(
        title,
        msg,
        progress,
        {
            // Disable keyboard ESC to close dialogue instances
            keyboard: false,

            // lock the background window
            backdrop: "static",
            size: "sm",
            windowClass: "ult-loading modal-message",
            animation: false
        }
    );

    // Push the dialog into the pool
    dlgs.push(dlg);

    // Return the created dialog
    return dlg;
}
```

This dialog is never actually visible when running the test/ browsing to the page manually, so it seems to be some sort of 'background task' that is run while browsing to/ loading a new page. I should also note that this dialog is defined within a `factory`:

```
.factory('DialogMgr', function($rootScope, $document, dialogs) {
    ...
    function wait(...) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I'm wondering if this possibly has anything to do with the 'fade' animation that is set on the dialog? How would I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I know it's not considered 'best practice', the only way I was actually able to resolve this was to insert a `browser.sleep()` line just before the call to `browser.click()`:

```
it('should navigate to the Export page', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.wait(pageLoaded, 5000);
    browser.sleep(500);
    exportMenuBtn.click();
    browser.wait(EC.urlIs(site + '/#/export'), 5000);
});
```

using the `pageLoaded()` function that Ernst Zwingli provided in their answer:

```
var pageLoaded = function() {
    var blockingElement = $('div[window-class="ult-loading modal-message"');
    //console.log("blockingElement: ", blockingElement);
    return EC.invisibilityOf(blockingElement);
}
module.exports = new pageLoaded();
```

Without the call to `browser.sleep(500);`, the page did not have time for animation to complete on a dialog that was opened & closed in the background while the page was loading- meaning that the dialog received the click, rather than the menu button I had intended.

Answer (score 1):

This is [for 99% the same question as the one from November 10th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219952/angularjs-testing-with-protractor-cannot-read-property-click-of-undefined).

How does [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47225346/8683679) not satisfy your question?

I added the (though commented) line `browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(blockingElement), 5000);` as the answer to your problem.

The moment, an element `isClickable` doesn't automatically mean, it's also on the front and there is no other object overlaying it. It just means, that the object may receive a `click()`, because...

> element is visible and enabled such that you can click it

[Read more about here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable). You can even inspect the source code.

**UPDATE**

Given your comments you're having a dialog-popup blocking input, while the page is loading. Therefore you could create your own `ExpectedConditions`-function, which will always wait until that blocking dialog is gone.

Here is the re-usable function to build, based on the assumption, that this blocker-element will appear on many places:

```
var loaded = function(){
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var blockerElm = $('div[window-class="ult-loading"');
    return EC.invisibilityOf(blockerElm);
}
module.exports = new loaded();
```

Here is how to call it in your test case:

```
var loaded = require(pathToLoaded.js);
it('should navigate to the Charts page', function() {
    console.log("Start Charts page test");
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.wait(loaded, 5000);
    chartsMenuBtn.click(); //works, if the element is defined as you said
    browser.wait(EC.urlIs(site + '/#/charts'), 5000);
})
```

Comment: Where do you get the `blockingElement` from? The error in the console seems to suggest it's a dialog that would receive the click at this point, but there is no dialog displayed during the execution of the test (i.e. none of the lines executed navigate to a page where a dialog is displayed)...

Comment: The error says: `Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope ult-loading modal-message ng-animate in-remove in-remove-active" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" window-class="ult-loading modal-message" size="sm" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;; transition-property: opacity;transition-duration: 0.15s;">...</div>`, but there is no dialog displayed on these pages...

Comment: Just realised that the code section shown in the error message was not displayed properly in my OP- so have reformatted that.

Comment: The link to the Protractor API that you provided is exactly what I have been following to write my code

Comment: On the other question, where you posted the answer you referenced here, there is a dialog displayed- I haven't managed to get your answer working with that as yet, but will revisit it after I resolve the issue with this test. As I mentioned in this question, when initially writing up my tests, I had a `browser.pause();` line enabled, and as I ran through my tests manually (having to tell the script to continue at the execution of each line), they all passed correctly. I have only encountered this issue since removing the call to `browser.pause();` - so it appears to be a timing issue...

Comment: proposed a way, how you can create a re-usable waiter-function to always wait your blocking Element to disappear. I'm not sure, if I properly identified your blocking Element, but you may of course change that Identifier to what will uniquely identify it.

Comment: Thanks for the update- I gave that a go, but still seem to be getting the same error message. This did help me find the dialog that it's complaining about though- will update my OP to show that now.